# Attribute “partition” not found - error with mkfs.vfat

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-17.04

I have a USB flash drive that's become unrecognisable in Windows 7, as [detailed in my question on SuperUser here](https://superuser.com/questions/1240316/usb-flash-drive-not-recognisable-and-causing-strange-behaviour/1240325). I was advised to try using Ubuntu, and was able to see the flash drive using it, although using Disks to zero-wipe, format it and create a new partition still didn't make it visible in Windows 7.

After using `dd` to zero-write the drive, and then using Disks to create a "FAT" partition, I started following [this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/546506/323079), and did the command:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdc
```

I got the error:

> Attribute "partition" not found

...and the command stopped running.

I tried again, this time formatting the drive in Disks and then using Gparted to create a "fat32" partition table, followed by a partition that I formatted as fat32, but still got the same error.

It seems to me that the error has something to do with the `-I` switch, but I'd rather not omit it because I feel like it may be a necessary step to getting my USB successfully recognised again. I've checked in Disks, and it does report the drive as having a (single, FAT) partition.

#### **What exactly does the *Attribute "partition" not found* error mean, and how can I get rid of it?**

Comment: You tried to format the entire device. You need to first create a partition e.g. with fdisk or gparted and then format that partition.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I created a partition after formatting. I did this the first time using Disks to create a "FAT" partition, and then with the gparted GUI to create a fat32 partition. I always get the same error. Edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: The fat32 partition you created should be `/dev/sdc1`. You only need `-I` to format a raw device but not for a partition.

Comment: So you're saying that the USB either needs to have no partition (i.e. be a raw drive) or, if it has a partition, run the `mkfs.vfat` command on  `/dev/sdc1`, and without the `-I` switch?

Comment: Yes, but you could also use gparted to format the partition.

Comment: btw. you can also try the [sd formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). It's designed for sd cards but should also work fine on usb sticks.

Comment: Okay, that worked, and I was able to enter all those commands without error. However, I'm now unable to see the newly-partitioned USB in the launcher, and so I'm not sure how to remove it safely. Is it normal for the USB not to appear in the launcher when it was before? Will powering it off from Disks be equivalent to safely removing it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same problem and couldn't find an answer, so I had to figure out how to solve it on my own.

Apparently, the issue is that there is no partition within the disk. So, I first partitioned the disk using the following command:

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`

Press 'n' to create a new partition. You will be asked for the partition number, the first sector, and the last sector. Press 'Enter' to maintain the default values.

After creating the new partition, you need to write these configurations to the disk. Just type 'w', and the configuration will be written to the disk, exiting fdisk.

Now, you have one partition inside your disk, and you should address this partition in your command line: sdc -> sdc1. Then, execute the following command:

`sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdc1`

Now, your Linux or Windows system will recognize the partition.